# Amazon AWS S3 Transfer Tracking - Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 in my android app for uploading files to the cloud storage.
Every user can upload and download files from the cloud storage i.e. S3
I want to keep **track of every user's upload and download...** for eg User abc uploaded 26MB and downloaded 94MB

One solution to this is to implement this on my mobile app, store/track size while uploading and downloading.

Does AWS lets us know via any analytics or is there any other 3rd party api which gives transfer details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS Console` does not provide any useful method to track user's `upload` and `download`, One suggestion is that you should post these information using locally if you have a `local database`, but if you have a `remote database` to save your records you may send these informations to your server using `web service`.